# Confused updating JSON conditionally in loop

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a JS code that should do the below.

1. loop over the json array.
2. based on the condition, add a new element to the json array.

Here is the code that I wrote.

```js
var a = [{
    'fName': 'a',
    'lName': 'b'
  },
  {
    'fName': 'a',
    'lname': 'c'
  },
  {
    'fName': 'x',
    'lName': 'z'
  }
];

var aClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
a.forEach(item => {
  if (item.fName == 'a') {
    aClone['newName'] = 'ab';
  } else if (item.fName = 'x') {
    aClone['newName'] = 'cd';
  }
});

console.log(aClone);
```

I know that there is some error in my code, but unable to figure out where it is.

My expected outcome is as below.

```
[
  {
    "fName": "a",
    "lName": "b",
    "newName": "ab"
  },
  {
    "fName": "a",
    "lname": "c",
    "newName": "ab"
  },
  {
    "fName": "x",
    "lName": "z",
    "newName": "cd"
  }
]
```

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it. Your main issue was this:

```js
aClone['newName'] = 'ab';
```

It should be this instead:

```js
item['newName'] = 'ab';
```

### Suggestion

You can reduce some of your code by mapping directly off of the clone.

1. Use `map` instead of `forEach`
2. Modify the `item` instead
3. Return the `item`

```js
var a = [{
  'fName': 'a',
  'lName': 'b'
}, {
  'fName': 'a',
  'lname': 'c'
}, {
  'fName': 'x',
  'lName': 'z'
}];

var aClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a)).map(item => {
  if (item.fName == 'a') {
    item['newName'] = 'ab';
  } else if (item.fName = 'x') {
    item['newName'] = 'cd';
  }
  return item;
});

console.log(aClone);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Alternative

Here is an alternative approach, using the spread operator to clone the item and apply a new property calculated by a switch.

```js
var a = [{
  'fName': 'a',
  'lName': 'b'
}, {
  'fName': 'a',
  'lname': 'c'
}, {
  'fName': 'x',
  'lName': 'z'
}];

const calcNewName = (item) => {
  switch (item.fName) {
    case 'a' : return 'ab';
    case 'x' : return 'cd';
    default  : return null;
  }
}

const aClone = a.map(item => ({ ...item, 'newName' : calcNewName(item) }));

console.log(aClone);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```